# Click event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a little new to HTML, CSS et al. I'm having trouble with the click event on a html page.

HTML

```
<div class="Box1 DaddyBox"></div>
<div class="Box2 DaddyBox"></div>
<div class="Box3 DaddyBox"></div>
```

CSS

```
.DaddyBox{
    border:thick;
    border-color:#FFF;
}

.DaddyBox:hover{
    background: green;
}

.Box1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 96px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 96px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #F5E255;  
}
```

JS

```
$('.Box1').click(function(){
    alert(Alert)
});
```

Is there something glaringly obvious that I'm missing?  I am not getting the alert on click of the Box.

If clarity is required, I'm trying to create a grid like interface for a website.  Each box will link to a new page.  Again, I'm new to this and am only attempting what I have learned so far, so perhaps I am way off, feel free to point me in a new direction.

Thanks

Comment: learn basics of javascript, before you learn jQuery, 
Alert is a variable ,
"Alert" is a String .

Understand Difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed quotes for the message in [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert), change to:

```
....
alert("Alert");
...
```

and include jQyery library, and wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` if not already done, as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.Box1').click(function(){
        alert("Alert"); //add quotes to your message Alert
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

include java library in header

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.Box1').click(function(){
        alert("Alert"); //add quotes  
    });
});
```